# Find the number of triangles formed by n lines.

Tags: geometry, algorithms

You are given $n$ lines with equations $ax+by+c=0$. Moreover, no $3$ lines pass through the same point. You have to find the number of triangles that can be formed using these lines.

Input

First line of input contains $N$ - number of lines. $N$ lines follow, each line contains three integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ corresponding to the formula of $i$th line. Moreover, $a$ and $b$ will not be simultaneously $0$ for a line.

Output

Output a single integer corresponding to the number of triangles formed by these $N$ lines.

Constraints

`1<=N<=300000`
`|a|,|b|,|c|<=10^9`

Sample Input -

```
6  
0 1 0  
-5 3 0  
-5 -2 25  
0 1 -3  
0 1 -2  
-4 -5 29
```

Sample Output -
`10`

Comment: This question would belong better on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Benjamin that's totally incorrect. Codegolf is for obtaining the shortest possible solution to a programming puzzle. This is a simple algorithms problem.

Comment: @Newb Oh, then I am misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @Benjamin the OP should really be asking this on StackOverflow -- it's a standard CS/Algorithms problem.

Comment: Moreover, and I think it is the most important, the OP could show us what he/she has already done...

Comment: Take care of parallel lines ! Besides, duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/260037)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question mentioned by some in the comments. Moreover, I first posted it on Stack Overflow, where people down-voted the question, stating that it should be asked on Math.StackExchange

Comment: I understand that it is not a duplicate strictly speaking of the reference I gave because you have asked for an algorithm (which, IMHO has not much  interest): it is easily done by **3 nested "for" loops** taking care of the cases where 2 (or 3) of the lines are parallel (lines with equation $a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0$ and $a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0$ are parallel iff $a_1b_2 =  a_2b_1$)